# How to pass the List from the Recylerview to the Class

Tags: android, arraylist, interface

I want to pass the arraylist from the Recylerview to the class , how i can achieve it ?

Here is my custom filter class

```
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

    FilterResults filterResults=new FilterResults();
    if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0){
        constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
         filterArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
            if(arrayList.get(i).getId().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                filterArrayList.add(arrayList.get(i));
            }
        }

        filterResults.count=filterArrayList.size();
        filterResults.values=filterArrayList;
    }else{

        filterResults.count= arrayList.size();
        filterResults.values=arrayList;
    }
    return filterResults;
}

@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    //Here i want the arraylist from the recylerview without making the arraylist static
    // adapter.items= (List<OrderPogo>) results.values;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: See my answer here. Inside the Custom Adapter class there is a method called filter() and it will give you the ArrayList when you call it from the Activity.

Comment: or just make it static :-D

Comment: i want the arraylist in on publishResults

Comment: i don't want to make static so i i wrote on the comment

Answer (score 0):

You should actually get the arrayList on performFiltering method. After filtering the list, at the end you can write

```
filterResults.values = yourList;
filterResults.count = yourList.size();
```

and then

```
return filterResults
```

You will get the filtered results list on publishResults method via

```
result.values
```

The best way to access your arrayList inside the Filter class is to create your Filter class inside RecycleView.